# How to write test cases for a init function by Unit test in python?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm new in Python. I have a `__init__` function with information about data sink config and I have to write some test cases fot it. But `init` is a function which doesn't return any result so confuses me. Can you show me some ways to implement test case for it ? Thank you.

My function :

```
class DataSinkConfig():
    DEFAULT_ENTRIES_TABLE = 'entries'
    DEFAULT_OUTLIERS_TABLE = 'outliers'
    DEFAULT_OUTLIERCAUSES_TABLE = 'outlier_causes'

    # Note
    def __init__(self, dbconf):

        insopt = dbconf.get('insopt')
        if insopt is None:
            self.entries_table_name = self.DEFAULT_ENTRIES_TABLE
            self.outliers_table_name = self.DEFAULT_OUTLIERS_TABLE
            self.outlier_causes_table_name = self.DEFAULT_OUTLIERCAUSES_TABLE
        else:
            try:
                dict(insopt)
            except Exception as e:
                raise Exception(
                    "Invalid value {} for parameter 'insopt'.".format(insopt))

            self.entries_table_name = self.__complement_item(insopt, 'entry_tbl', self.DEFAULT_ENTRIES_TABLE)
            self.outliers_table_name = self.__complement_item(insopt, 'outlier_tbl', self.DEFAULT_OUTLIERS_TABLE)
            self.outlier_causes_table_name = self.__complement_item(insopt, 'cause_tbl', self.DEFAULT_OUTLIERCAUSES_TABLE)
```

My test is stuck :

```
import unittest
import DataSinkConfig, DataSourceConfig

class TestDataSink(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self): 
      #pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: `__init__` does the initalization of the object after is has been created, so you have to check the object state in a test. Generally, any method that does not return anything can only be tested by its side effects (e.g. the changed state of objects), so that's not specific to `__init__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do stuff like check the state on the object.
Obviously you can move DataSink instantiation to the setUp method.

```
import unittest
import DataSinkConfig, DataSourceConfig

class TestDataSink(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self): 
      #pass

    def test_data_sink(self):
        dsc = DataSinkConfig(db_conf)
        self.assertEqual(dsc.entries_table_name, "WHATREVER COMPLIMENT ITEM WAS SUPPOSE TO SET")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```